# Get vertex numbers of CGAL polygon intersection

Tags: c++, performance, cgal

I want to efficiently create a list of the vertex number of a polygon that intersects. This in order to check if I move the polygons slightly I can check whether it is the same intersection or a completely different one. Presumably if at least one vertex number remains in the list it is the same intersection.

So I have polygon P and Q at t=0 intersecting, this should give me vertex number [1,2,3] for P and [2] for polygon Q, see image for clarification. At t=1 I would get [1,2] for P and [2] for Q.

[image: Intersecting polygons at two timesteps]

Currently I first retrieve the intersection and than for both polygons loop through the vertices and use the has_on_boundary function to determine if it is part of the intersection and store the vertex number. See code:

```
//Standard Includes
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

//Include CGAL options
#define CGAL_HEADER_ONLY 1 //Defining to use the CGAL library as header only
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Boolean_set_operations_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>

//Typedefs for CGAL Uses.
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2                                 Point_2;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<Kernel>                         Polygon_2;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_with_holes_2<Kernel>              Polygon_with_holes_2;
typedef std::vector<Polygon_with_holes_2>               Pwh_list_2;

int main() {
    Polygon_2 P;
    P.push_back(Point_2(-1, 1));
    P.push_back(Point_2(-0.01, -1));
    P.push_back(Point_2(0, -1));
    P.push_back(Point_2(0.01, -1));
    P.push_back(Point_2(1, 1));

    Polygon_2 Q;
    Q.push_back(Point_2(-1, -1));
    Q.push_back(Point_2(1, -1));
    Q.push_back(Point_2(0, 1));

    Pwh_list_2 polygon_intersections;
    CGAL::intersection(P, Q, std::back_inserter(polygon_intersections));
    //For ease now only assume one intersection
    Polygon_2 intersection = polygon_intersections[0].outer_boundary();

    //Get vertex number of P in intersection
    int vertex_nr = 0;
    std::set<int> overlapping_vertices_P;
    cout << "Find intersection vertices of Polygon P" << endl;
    for (auto it = P.vertices_begin(); it != P.vertices_end(); ++it, ++vertex_nr)   {
        if (intersection.has_on_boundary(*it)) {
            overlapping_vertices_P.insert(vertex_nr);
            cout << vertex_nr << endl;
        }
    }

    //Get vertex number of Q in intersection
    vertex_nr = 0;
    std::set<int> overlapping_vertices_Q;
    cout << "Find intersection vertices of Polygon Q" << endl;
    for (auto it = Q.vertices_begin(); it != Q.vertices_end(); ++it, ++vertex_nr)   {
        if (intersection.has_on_boundary(*it)) {
            overlapping_vertices_Q.insert(vertex_nr);
            cout << vertex_nr << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Question:** It works but seems very inefficient to me. Is there a better way to do this?

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the CGAL::Arrangement_2 data structure. Insert the polygons into a CGAL::Polygon_set_2 construct (from the CGAL Boolean_set_operations_2 package), extract the arrangement from it, and traverse the faces of the extracted arrangement.

Comment: Just to give an answer, thanks for you comment and I will look into that direction as soon as I have time, and hopefully can post an answer to my own question. On a side note I think I will just order your book which I think will be of great help.